# Tomcat on Eclipse Juno and Luna. One works, the other one doesn't

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-mars

I am working on JavaEE webprojects using maven for dependencies and so on. The testing environment is Tomcat 7 for eclipse.

Now, when I made the transition to the newer eclipse (Luna) and deploy the webapp on tomcat, the tomcat instance refuses to serve the project. It gives 404 and the request on `localhost:8080` doesn't produce any unusual console or log entries except the normal startup output (the exact same as on Juno).

I compared the server access log files located in `/.metadata/...` and the startup scripts. They are equal. No error messages, and no other clues on why the Luna Tomcat does not work. Don't get me wrong, the server 'works', as it provides a 404 message, it just does not serve the webapp that is deployed.

Does somebody have an idea on how to debug this further, or what the reason for the different behaviour could be? Thanks for any hints or advice.

-a

EDIT:
Just a few things I already did:
- Check and set project root (set to / in both cases)
- One suggestion found via google was to fiddle with the Libraries and Order and Export in Project Settings Build Path. (just move them up and down to get rid of a bug -> did not work)
- In Project Properties, set the targeted runtime to Tomcat 7 (the server in question)
- Reinstall the server
- Copy all configuration from one server path to the other.
- Set the server base path of Luna to the exact same as the working Juno instance (yes, they are in different places)

EDIT2:
Updating Eclipse to the newest version (MARS) did the job. Sadly I will now never know what the cause of the problem was. Luckily everything works again and I can focus on actually doing something :D

Comment: Hi! I did that transition a fews ago (actually from Kepler to Luna) with no problem. One issue I do remember is that I got weird errors (not a 404 that I recall) until I reinstalled all the needed packages for web development in Luna. Hope it helps.

Comment: Sec, I'll try that. There was that one post which emphasized the need of Eclipse for JavaEE development, but since I have exactly that, I thought there was no need. brb

Comment: Okay. Sadly, I solved the problem without knowing what it was. I just installed Eclipse Mars, installed a Tomcat7 Server and got the project working on it without any hassle at all. I'm not to sure how about going with this 'solution' for this thread. Updating eclipse to a newer version did the job.